# Pre made functional camera available?

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-camera

I am creating an android application that will need to capture images from the front camera but this function is by far not the main purpose of the application.

I was wondering if there are any pre made custom views that manage and make use of the android Camera object to take a picture but which wraps all the basic camera functions (zoom, focus etc. including the interface) within it and returns me a final image when the user has captured a photo. Does such a thing exist?

I know it seems lazy but it would benefit me to focus on the unique parts of the application instead.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't this exactly why we have Intents? So that we can request to use other applications? Every device with a camera has a camera app, so use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use intent to do this task ::

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(intent, cameraRequestCode);
```

and inside onActivityResult ::

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {  
    if ( (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) && (requestCode == cameraRequestCode)) 
    {  
        Bitmap myPicture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap( myPicture );
    }  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know much about intents. Does the new activity run asynchronously? Because there are running processes in my main activity that I would like to continue while the user is taking a picture.

Comment: you can read about intent here :: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html